# Petition to make special

Tags: uspto, application

If I have already received a first office action in the USPTO, will filing a petition to make special (e.g., based on age) speed up subsequent actions?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the benefit of an application to make special comes from reduced queue time to be initially picked up by the examiner. You are past that point, but there are requirements for quick action at other points in the process as well and, since there is no fee, I would recommend applying for this program.